# using ANT uptodate where multiple source files create multiple output files

Tags: ant, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to do an Ant build where one step involves running ANTLR whenever one or more *.g4 or *.stg files change.  If any of these changes, then I need to run the ANTLR task if any of the *.java or *.tokens files in my output directory are older than any of the *.g4 or *.stg files.

I'm looking at the ant  task, but not seeing how to set up a mapper to express this dependency.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the way I do it for the intellij plug-in here: https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/blob/master/build.gradle

intellij uses gradle now for plugin dev.

Comment: [chuckle] if you think typing xml and using ANT is easy ;)

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy In future, please include the relevant code in your answer in case the link becomes broken. This is a working link to the code in question at the time of the answer: https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/blob/9027a7542d20df2decc5f71599d1c9bd3d1188b0/build.xml

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: fixed the link.